# WebStorm/Cucumber: Undefined step reference

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, webstorm

I'm using Windows 7 x64 and Cucumber, Selenium and Node are installed using `-g`. In the WebStorm I'm using cucumber-js.cmd, because others don't work as they are not for x64.

Trying to run [this example from GitHub](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/master/docs/nodejs_example.md) and when I run using the Windows command line everything works, but when I run it using WebStorm I get an error that says that my steps are not defined, even though my `feature` is in the `features` folder and my `step definitions` are in the `step_definitions` folder.

Can't find anything decent in google to solve this as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Several problems here:

- Cucumber 2.0 is not currently supported: [WEB-25324](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-25324)
- step definitions are not recognized if they are described using simple string literals instead of regular expressions: [WEB-15600](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-15600)

please follow these tickets for updates

Comment: I can rewrite the step definitions as regular expressions, but will Cucumber 2.0 be supported anytime soon ?

Comment: yes, hopefully. Please vote for WEB-25324 to be notified when it's fixed